# Capistorano deploy SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError : rake exit status: 1

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-5, capistrano, web-deployment

Thank you for checking out my issue.
I have an error with the capistorano right now.
Have been struggling with this error for few days, so please help me out.
I am using the Active storage in the app.
The keys are in the /etc/environment.
Just in case in the credentials too.(AWS IAM keys)
Details are bellow.
Please tell me if you need more info, I really appreciate if you could help me out.
Thank you.

#### Error log

```
00:12 deploy:assets:precompile
      01 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile
#<Thread:0x00007fa8bc548e10@/Users/coro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sshkit-1.20.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:10 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
Traceback (most recent call last):
    1: from /Users/coro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sshkit-1.20.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/Users/coro/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sshkit-1.20.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute': Exception while executing as ec2-user@18.176.69.6: rake exit status: 1 (SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError)
rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: Nothing written
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as ec2-user@18.176.69.6: rake exit status: 1
rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: Nothing written


Caused by:
SSHKit::Command::Failed: rake exit status: 1
rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: Nothing written

Tasks: TOP => deploy:assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as ec2-user@18.176.69.6: rake exit status: 1
rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: Nothing written


** DEPLOY FAILED
** Refer to log/capistrano.log for details. Here are the last 20 lines:
```

#### Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.1'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.4.4'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
# gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
# gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: %i[mri mingw x64_mingw]
  gem 'capistrano'
  gem 'capistrano-rbenv'
  gem 'capistrano-bundler'
  gem 'capistrano-rails'
  gem 'capistrano3-unicorn'
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'rubocop', require: false
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :production do
  gem 'unicorn', '5.4.1'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'active_hash'
gem "aws-sdk-s3", require: false
gem "devise"
gem 'dotenv-rails'
gem 'font-awesome-sass'
gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'pry-rails'
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: %i[mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby]
```

#### Capfile

```
require "capistrano/setup"
require "capistrano/deploy"
require "capistrano/scm/git"
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git

require "capistrano/rbenv"
require "capistrano/bundler"
require "capistrano/rails/assets"
require "capistrano/rails/migrations"
require 'capistrano3/unicorn'
Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

#### deploy.rb

```
lock '3.11.2'

set :application, 'datingapp'

set :repo_url,  'git@github.com:coro-from-Kyoto/DatingApp.git'

set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system', 'public/uploads')

set :rbenv_type, :user
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.5.1'

set :ssh_options, auth_methods: ['publickey'],
                  keys: ['~/.ssh/DatingAppPort.pem'] 

set :unicorn_pid, -> { "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid" }

set :unicorn_config_path, -> { "#{current_path}/config/unicorn.rb" }
set :keep_releases, 5

set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push("config/master.key")


after 'deploy:publishing', 'deploy:restart'
namespace :deploy do
  task :restart do
    invoke 'unicorn:restart'
  end
end
```

#### Unicorn.rb

```
app_path = File.expand_path('../../../', __FILE__)

worker_processes 1

working_directory "#{app_path}/current"

pid "#{app_path}/shared/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"

listen "#{app_path}/shared/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock"

stderr_path "#{app_path}/shared/log/unicorn.stderr.log"

stdout_path "#{app_path}/shared/log/unicorn.stdout.log"

timeout 60

preload_app true
GC.respond_to?(:copy_on_write_friendly=) && GC.copy_on_write_friendly = true

check_client_connection false

run_once = true

before_fork do |server, worker|
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) &&
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!

  if run_once
    run_once = false # prevent from firing again
  end

  old_pid = "#{server.config[:pid]}.oldbin"
  if File.exist?(old_pid) && server.pid != old_pid
    begin
      sig = (worker.nr + 1) >= server.worker_processes ? :QUIT : :TTOU
      Process.kill(sig, File.read(old_pid).to_i)
    rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH => e
      logger.error e
    end
  end
end

after_fork do |_server, _worker|
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) && ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

Answer (score 4):

I got this error because I did not have `npm` and `yarn` installed on the server

Answer (score 2):

It seems the server connection was cut abruptly.

Can you check the server if it still has enough disk space?

Also, can you try manually running asset-compile IN the server and see what happens.

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:precompile
```

※change to staging or development(depends on your environment).

Comment: ,Thanks you for your knowledge.
I still have plenty of disk space.
Should I use the command in the ssh? or just in the local server. 
When I used it in the local server, I failed because of a ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free.
Could you please give me more info about the command?

Comment: execute it in ssh under the working directory. What is the project path btw?

Comment: I tried it but nothing changed.Also added config.assets.compile = true code but no change. its /var/www/app/.

Comment: So the precompile-command ran successfully with no errors in the remote server?

Comment: Assets are compiled successfully but still cap production deploy fails.

Comment: yes, it seems to be server space issue, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yep! If you `--trace` the deploy command, the **deploy:assets:precompile** stage will fail at **SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError:** meaning that the prod server can't process your request correctly. Try installing **nodejs** and **yarn** on the user you deploy to.  Docker simplifies the stack by abstracting much of the production configuration from the developer.

```
cap production deploy --trace

sudo apt-get install nodejs

curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -

echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list

sudo apt update

sudo apt install yarn
```